# Replacement for chmod --reference on OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, jenkins

I'm trying to port some jenkins bash scripts from Ubuntu to OS X. The linux (and I think it is originally GNU) chmod has a --reference option that allows copying the mode from a reference file. I am looking for the equivalent code for OS X, preferably without installing extra packages. Even better would be a cross-platform solution.

The concrete snippet:

```
# expand all the templates
find "$OUTPUT_PATH" -name "*.template" | while read FILE ; do
    sed \
        -e "s/%{NAME}/$OPTION_NAME/g" \
        -e "s/%{TITLE}/$OPTION_TITLE/g" \
        -e "s/%{VERSION}/$OPTION_VERSION/g" \
        -e "s/%{WHEN}/$OPTION_WHEN/g" \
            "$FILE" > "${FILE%.*}"
    chmod --reference="$FILE" "${FILE%.*}"
    rm -f "$FILE"
done
```

[edit] The combination of stat -r with saving the file mode is the right combination, stat -c doesn't exist on OS X

Comment: Cross-platform shell script, that's a good one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your OS X has the `stat` command

```
# expand all the templates
find "$OUTPUT_PATH" -name "*.template" | while read FILE ; do
    savemod=$(stat -c "%a" "$FILE")
    sed \
        -e "s/%{NAME}/$OPTION_NAME/g" \
        -e "s/%{TITLE}/$OPTION_TITLE/g" \
        -e "s/%{VERSION}/$OPTION_VERSION/g" \
        -e "s/%{WHEN}/$OPTION_WHEN/g" \
            "$FILE" > "${FILE%.*}"
    chmod $savemod "${FILE%.*}"

    rm -f "$FILE"
done
```

If it doesn't have `-c` option, check the [man page of stat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) under formatting. you can find similar ways to get the permission/mode of the file.

Comment: `stat(1)` doesn’t have a `-c` option.

Comment: I think you'd have to `stat -r $FILE | cut -f3 -d' '` on OSX to get the octal permissions bitmap. The `-r` outputs the "raw" contents of the `struct stat` and the third column is the file mode.

Comment: Looking at the man page, there are similar ways the same as `-c` but i don't own OS X so can't test.

Comment: @Bavarious: I guess I read faster than you :) @bash-o-logist: `stat -r` and bit of `cut` to slice out the interesting part works.

Comment: @mu is too short. Found some other answers of you to vote up :)

Answer (score 3):

Copy the file first and only then overwrite with a shell redirection. This should preserve the original permissions.

Answer (score 3):

How about using the format switch to FreeBSD stat:

```
stat -f "%p" ~/.bashrc
stat -f "%Sp" ~/.bashrc

stat -f "%u:%g:%p" ~/.bashrc
```